# Getting yaw/heading of device

Tags: android, android-sensors

There are many examples here in stackoverflow on how to combine the Accelerometer and Gyroscope in order to retrieve the Azimuth, Pitch and Roll.

Is it possible to calculate the Yaw/Heading of the device, by using the rotation matrix from the SensorManager.getOrientation()?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Azimuth is Yaw/Heading

Comment: @HoanNguyen you are right. Even though Azimuth and Yaw has a tiny difference to their definition, it can be used as the same thing.

Comment: From the rotation matrix you can extract pretty much any information about the device. You just have to be more specific of what you are trying to do to get more helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SensorManager.getOrientation(float[] R, float[] values)` requires a rotation matrix as *input*. The output is stored in the `values` array.

`values[0]` is the azimuth/yaw/heading (all the same thing).

Since there is no rotation matrix *from* `SensorManager.getOrientation()`, the answer to your original question is **no**.

However, `SensorManager.getOrientation()` **can** be used to *extract* the azimuth/yaw/heading (as well as pitch and roll) **from** a rotation matrix that you got from somewhere else.

There is no magical way of getting the output. You either have to use one of the built in fused sensors (like the *rotation vector*), or implement your own solution with the base sensors (gyroscope, accelerometer, magnetometer). Be aware that you *will* depend on the magnetometer to determine your azimuth/yaw/heading, since none of the other sensors can measure that aspect of orientation.

[Sensor Manager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float[],%20float[]))

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct and that is how I am getting the values I need from the sensors. Even though it does not solve my problem (which was in fact something else that had nothing to do with yaw/azimuth), I marked it as correct for future readers.